# TypeLoadException when I try to get a SQLite connection from Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, xamarin.forms, typeloadexception, sqlite.net

I'm currently developping a Windows Phone application with Xamarin.Forms.
To do that, I need to use a SQLite database in order to have a cross-platform application with Android and iOS.

So i followed the steps described in the following document : [Working with a local database using SQLite.Net with Xamarin.Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/offline.pdf)

The thing is I'm getting an error when I try to get a SQLite connection on Windows Phone 8 with the following code :

```
var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.SQLitePlatformWP8();
```

The call of this method throws a TypeLoadException with this message :

```
[System.TypeLoadException] = {System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExtendedErrCode' in type 
'SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.SQLiteApiWP8' from assembly
'SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
does not have an implementation.
at SQL...
```

I have no idea for the reason why I'm getting such an error. If you have any idea, it would be great !

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to help me

Comment: The thing I don't understant is that in my NuGet Package Manager, it is said the installed version of SQLite.Net PCL - WindowsPhone8 Platform is the version 2.4.0 while the error message says 'Version=2.3.0.0'.

Can it be related to the problem I m getting?

Comment: Definitely check out versions (check where references are pointing).

Comment: There is an incoherence : my references are from version 2.3.0.0 while I added the version 2.4.0 from my NuGet Package Manager. But I only found this problem for the SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8. The SQLite.Net reference is on version 2.4.0.0.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As I said, check out where are references located (Project/References) and check what's inside packages folder created by NuGet.

Comment: When I go to the properties of the SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8 package, I find this :
* Version 2.3.0.0
* ...\packages\SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.2.4.0\lib\windowsphone8\x86\SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.dll

So the folder says version 2.4.0 but not the version specified in the properties

Comment: Perhaps a problem with nuget package.

Comment: Have you any idea of how I can fix it?

Comment: If the problem is really the package then you can't fix it. Perhaps you can get the sources and prepare/reference assemblies manually. Or checkout an earlier or a prerelease (if there is any with the fix) package version.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the version in the Visual Studio extension for Sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

If you see in reference property path of  SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8 there's a link to x86 Platform system. Remove the reference and search in nuget package installed ARM Platform and all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error adding [assembly: Dependency (typeof (SQLite_WinPhone))] in AssemblyInfo.cs
but now I've another error.